# Several questions regarding, image resizing (viewport)

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am having some Issues with how my images are aligned on my website. 
 1. I would the images to have equal spacing from the left and the right, meaning centered because currently as you make the browser smaller the right side is a lot bigger than the left. 
 2. Also as I make the browser smaller the page realigns nice, but when I view it on a mobile device it is very different.
 
You can find my code at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpKvMx

```js
$("#myinput").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (val === "")
        $('img').show();
    else {
        $('img').hide();
        val = val.split(" ").join("\\ ");
        console.log(val)
        $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show();
    }
});

$(".img").wrap('<div class="alt-wrap"/>');

$(".img").each(function() {
    $(this).after('<p class="alt">' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</p>');
  })
```

```css
h1 {
 color: red;
} 
h2 {
 color:red;
}
p {
 font-family: Arial;
}
body {
 background-color: grey;
}
div { 
 text-align: justify; 
}
div img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
 max-height: 200px;
 height: auto; 
}

 input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
 
.alt-wrap { 
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px;
      color: whitesmoke;
      border: 1px solid mediumorchid;
}

.alt-wrap p.alt {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0; /* hide initially */
      left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 22px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      transition: all 300ms ease;
      transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.alt-wrap:hover > p.alt { 
      opacity: 1; 
      transition-delay: 0s;
}
    
.imgContainer{
    float:left;
}
img {
width: 200px !important; 

}
body {
background: white !important; 
}
.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.imgContainer:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dl {
margin-top: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
 <title>Title</title>
 <head>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <h1 align=center>Heading</h1>
  <h2 align=center>Sub-Heading</h2>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <input type="text" id="myinput" name="search" placeholder="Search.." style="border-radius: 4px;">
 </head>
 
 <br>
 <br>
 <body>
 
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <a href="cryptos/generic.html"><img src="https://i.warosu.org/data/biz/img/0063/87/1515861781137.png" alt="Bitcoin"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Bitcoin</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/ETHEREUM-YOUTUBE-PROFILE-PIC.png" alt="Ethereum"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ethereum</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://www.profitconfidential.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/ripple-icon-1-300x300.png" alt="Ripple"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ripple</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/Bitcoin_Cash.png" alt="Bitcoin Cash"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Bitcoin Cash</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/ada.png" alt="Cardano"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Cardano</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/NEM.png" alt="NEM"> <div class="overlay"><div class="text">NEM</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/Litecoin.png" alt="LiteCoin"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">LiteCoin</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/stellar.png" alt="Stellar Lumens"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Stellar Lumens</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/iota.png" alt="IOTA"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">IOTA</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/dash.png" alt="Dash"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Dash</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/neo.png" alt="NEO"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">NEO</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/tron.png" alt="Tron"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Tron</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/monero.png" alt="Monero"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Monero</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/eos.png" alt="EOS"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">EOS</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/icon.png" alt="ICON"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">ICON</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/bitcoingold.png" alt="Bitcoin Gold"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Bitcoin Gold</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/qtum.svg" alt="QTUM"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">QTUM</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/ethereum_classic.png" alt="Ethereum Classic"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ethereum Classic</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/raiblocks.png" alt="RaiBlocks"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">RaiBlocks</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/lisk.png" alt="Lisk"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Lisk</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/verge.png" alt="Verge"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Verge</div></div></a>   
    </div>
 <div class="imgContainer">
          <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://199.180.133.206/img/omisego.png" alt="OmiseGo"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">OmiseGO</div></div></a>   
    </div>
    
</div><br>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) All you need is to add the following css to the element you want to align horizontally: `margin: 0 auto;`

2) Use media queries, so for example you can have:

- on mobile: all the images stacked (you may need `width:100%` on your image container)
- for wider viewports: images inlined as in your code sample

If you are not confortable with media queries please see the following example: https://codepen.io/TrentWalton/pen/kqxDy.